# Substituting cot(x) with an identity in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Assume:
$$\cos(x) / \cot(x) = 0\tag A$$
I rewrite it as
$$\cos(x)/ \left(\cos(x)/\sin(x)\right) = 0\tag B$$
and get
$$\sin(x) = 0\tag C$$
This implies $x = 180^\circ\times k$

But, under (B), if $\sin(x) = 0$ I get undefined for $\cos(x)/\sin(x)$ and (C) would not be possible.

Also, $\cot(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: What do you mean "also $\cot(0) = undefined$"--it's undefined because $\sin(n\pi) = 0$.

Comment: There is no value of $x$ which makes (A) true.  There _are_ values of $x$ which make the following statement true: $\lim\limits_{\varphi \rightarrow x} \frac{\cos(\varphi)}{\cot(\varphi)} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens sometimes.  Since $\cot$ has a domain that excludes multiples of $180^\circ$, any "solutions" to an equation involving $\cot$ that are themselves mutliples of $180^\circ$ don't really exist.  These are called "[Extraneous (or Missing or Spurious) solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)".

Similarly, the equation $\cos(x) / \cot(x) = 1$ doesn't have any solutions *either*, because in order for it to happen you get $\sin(x)=1$ but that means $\cos(x)=\cot(x)=0$ and we're again dividing by zero.

In general, when trying to solve equations, you must beware of situations where the solution ends up not being in the valid domain of the original expressions.

Usually when this happens, it happens because naive simplification -- that is, simplification without keeping the domain restrictions in mind -- makes it look like it should work.  This also means that a graphical inspection looks like it should work too, if not done carefully.  Here's the correct graph of $\cos(x)/\cot(x)$:

[image: two periods of cos(x)/cot(x), which looks exactly like the graph of sin(x) except that every 90 degrees there's a dropout discontinuity]

Note the discontinuities every $90^\circ$.  These come from the fact that $\cot(x)$ is undefined for $x = 180^\circ \times k$ and zero (thus forcing division by zero) for $x = 90^\circ + 180^\circ \times k$, for integer $k$.  Most computer graphing systems will not show these, because it will only show if it happens to exactly pick an $x$ value that lands there.

Comment: This answer fails to address the fact that as $x$ approaches $n\pi$ that the original expression _does_ approach $0$.

Comment: Guess that could do with some mentioning, yes.  One moment whilst I prepare a visual aid...

Comment: What program did you use to make this graph?

Comment: Excel.  I added in the circles "by hand", selecting those individual entries and adding a marker with a white fill.